# How to clear CSS and Javascript with a bookmark?

Tags: caching

I would like to clear the CSS and javascript in D7 with the help of a bookmark.

Currently this is:

```
<domein>/admin_menu/flush-cache/assets?token=<tokenid>
```

This is working however the tokenid is changing all the time. It there a easy solution for this so I don't have to change the tokenid in the bookmark every time?

Comment: The token isn’t valid for long enough to make it worthwhile, plus it requires a valid cookie for an authenticated user to either use or generate a new one. Just use what admin_menu gives you, a cache clear button in a couple of hovers. You can always preprocess the menu item and add an accesskey attribute if you want a shortcut to it via the keyboard too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a custom module add a menu item (Using hook_menu) to function with this code:

```
drupal_clear_css_cache();
drupal_clear_js_cache();
```

Then you can just bookmark your custom page url. Or set a cron job to call that page at regular intervals if thats what you're after